# what's wrong with my jquery code?

Tags: jquery

html structure:

```
<form method="post" id="comment-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
 <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="30" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-mail">

 <input type="text" id="edit-mail" name="mail" value="" size="30" maxlength="64" class="form-text required" />

</div>

<div class="form-item  form-item-homepage">

 <input type="text" id="edit-homepage" name="homepage" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" class="form-text" />
</div>
<div  id="edit-comment-body">

<label for="edit-comment-body-und-0-value">comment <span title="required" class="form-required">*</span></label>

<textarea class="text-full form-textarea required" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-value" name="comment_body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#comment-form #edit-name").val()=='' || $("#comments #edit-email").val() =='' ||$("edit-comment-body"))
$("#comments #edit-submit").click(function(){
   $('#comment-form #edit-name').append('<span style="color:red;">please type your name</p>');
   $('#comment-form #edit-mail').append('<span style="color:red;">please type your emali</p>');
  $('#comment-form #edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">pleae type the content</p>');
});

});
```

i want to add some red text after the input text. but the above code can't work?what's wrong with my jquery code? thank you

Comment: How you tried debugging it in Chrome/Opera or Firefox+Firebug?

Comment: i am sorry, i am a new learner. i don't know how to debug them.

Comment: http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#jsexec or http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/

Comment: Your .append()'s are inserting <span></p> - So your HTML is invalid too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong - you use of selectors first of all is bad. You should stick to single id's where possible, e.g.:

```
$("#edit-submit")
```

Next problem is, you are wasting an **IF** statement - when the page first loads, you are checking if some inputs are blank - which they are likely to be, and still, even if they wern't you don't want someone to be able to empty and it pass as valid simply because the function which listens to the `.click()` wasn't added.

After the page loaded and the fields are blank, then you add a `.click()` listener to a button. It will be easier to add the `.click()` function to the button then check the validation always.

So for example you could change your jQuery to somehting like this:

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function(e) {
    var name = $('#edit-name');
    var mail = $('#edit-mail');
    var comment = $('#edit-comment-body-und-0-value');
    var blank = false;
    if (name.val()=='') {
        name.after('<span style="color:red;">please type your name</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (mail.val()=='') {
        mail.after('<span style="color:red;">please type your emali</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (comment.val()=='') {
        comment.after('<span style="color:red;">pleae type the content</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (blank) {
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
});
```

You will also need to add a submit button, *but I will assume you missed that off a copy paste of you HTML*:

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" value="submit" />
```

To explain the jQuery a little:

- Firstly get the values of the field you want to check.
- Now store a variable to check if any one field was blank.
- Now check each value to see if its blank.

  - If it was, use `.after()` to add your message, you can't append to an input, so place it after the input.
  - Also change the blank var for later in the code
- Finally check if the blank variable has been changed and stop the submit happening, otherwise the form will show the message(s) briefly as the browser submits the incorrect form.

To enhance your validation, you only want to error message once, and if the mistake has been corrected, but another still exists the corrected message should be removed (imagine multiple clicks on the submit).

To do this, add a class to your error message:

```
<span style="color:red;" class="error-message">please type your name</span>
```

And at the top of your function:

```
$('.error-message').remove();
```

So the final `.click()` function:

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function(e) {
    $('.error-message').remove();
    var name = $('#edit-name');
    var mail = $('#edit-mail');
    var comment = $('#edit-comment-body-und-0-value');
    var blank = false;
    if (name.val()=='') {
        name.after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message">please type your name</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (mail.val()=='') {
        mail.after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message">please type your emali</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (comment.val()=='') {
        comment.after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message">pleae type the content</span>');
        blank = true;
    }
    if (blank) {
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/YD29k/)

---

I will try to explain the `e.preventDefault()` part.
To start, the **IF** statement....basically an **IF** statement says:

```
if (what ever is in here is TRUE) {
    Do what ever code is written here....
}
```

So at the top of the `.click()` function we declare a variable called `blank` and set it to **FALSE**. So if no where in the code that follows that, up untill we get to the **IF** statement changes that to **TRUE** the code would not run.
So in the code, each time we check if one of the inputs is blank, we add a message and change `blank` to **TRUE**, so now the code in that **IF** statement will run.

On to the code, the [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)  this is a way to stop the browser doing what it would normally do by default.
So when we declare a callback function, in this case the `.click()` event, we are asking the jquery to listen out for clicks on something, so when it gets one, the event is also available within the code.
So imagine, since the begining of the web if someone clicks on a hyperlink *(`<a href=".....`)* the browser knows it needs to follow that link, regardless of what the jquery is doing, similarly if you submit a form, the browser knows it should follow the link declared in the declaration of the form.
Now because we don't want to submit the form **IF** there was a blank, we need to `preventDefault()` *(prevent the browser doing its default action)*.

To do this, when we declare the `.click(function(e) {`, we have declared a new variable `e` which is available within the function, `e` is the event which has caused the `.click()` function to be triggered - a click on a hyperlink, a click on a submit, a click on a picture even.
We could change things to slighlty longer code to make it easier to follow, for example: `e` to `event` *(infact anything you want)*:

```
.click(function(event) {
    var blanks_found = false; // No blanks found yet.
    ........
    blah
    blah
    blah
    ........
    if (blanks_found == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: i put the js code and the site's link and the image on my question. could you help me  find out why my code is wrong. thank you. you answer is great. many many thanks

Comment: Scoobler,what the use of the e argument?if (blank) {
        e.preventDefault();   
    } i don't understand this well? thank you

Comment: [zhuanzhou](http://stackoverflow.com/users/698574/zhuanzhou) - see you have gotten the help you need on your code from [Matt Ball](http://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball), so I have just added an explanation for `e.preventDefault();`, from the comments you left of Matt's code, it is the last bit you need.

Comment: But I still think you may not get the result you are looking for. Be careful as you are adding a click listener when a blank is found WHEN THE PAGE LOADS, and not checking for a blank every time the button is clicked! Once you add a `.click ()` callback, it remains in the background listening for a click.

Comment: yeah, i used  Matt Ball code. it's ok. but can't prevent the form submitting. so i useing e.preventDefault(); it's ok.your answer is also an answer. and make me know a lot. thanks very much.

Comment: No problem zhuanzhou glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

There is no element in the HTML you've provided with ID `comments`. There is also no element with ID `edit-submit`. Therefore the selector `$("#comments #edit-submit")` is not going to match any elements.

That means you're trying to bind a `click` listener to an element which does not exist.

---

In general, you should avoid overqualifying selectors. Because element IDs must be unique, an element ID selector is sufficient to match (at most) a single element. That means you can change the following:

- `$("#comment-form #edit-name")` to `$("#edit-name")`
- `$("#comments #edit-submit")` to `$("#edit-submit")`
- `$('#comment-form #edit-mail')` to `$('#edit-mail')`
- `$('#comment-form #edit-comment-body label span')` to
  `$('#edit-comment-body label span')`

---

> i have altered the code. it still can't work.

That's because `drupal.js` calls [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which leaves `window.jQuery` intact, but removes `window.$`. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your code, and pass `$` as a parameter to the document ready callback:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    if (!$("#edit-name").val() || !$("#edit-email").val() || !$("#edit-comment-body").val())
    {
        $("#edit-submit").click(function()
        {
            $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的名字</span>');
            $('#edit-mail').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的邮箱</span>');
            $('#edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">请填写内容</span>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i have altered the code. it still can't work. i put the link on my question

Comment: Open your console: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`. Since `jQuery` is defined but `$` isn't, `$.noConflict()` must have been called somewhere.

Comment: Matt Ball, you're my hero! it's only the last line can work.it's $('#edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">请填写内容</span>'). the above two lines can't work

Comment: Matt Ball,how do i let the user type content. if error,then show backend validate? if i use the above code. after ii click the button.the form is still submitted to the server. how to prevent it? thank you.

Comment: That's because you're trying to add an element as a child of an `<input/>`, which just doesn't make sense. Use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com). See my edit.

Comment: You should **really just use a validation plugin** as [@Keiron suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152777/whats-wrong-with-my-jquery-code/6152864#6152864).

Comment: your code is ok. many thanks. if i want to use your code and add a step.that is if show the red text then preventing the form to submit?how do i do?

Answer (score 2):

first mistake In

```
if($("#comment-form #edit-name").val()=='' || $("#comments #edit-email").val() =='' ||$("edit-comment-body"))
```

where is $('#comments') id used in html form ? ? ?

AND the second error should be

in your javascript.. you append a **span** with a closing tag of **P** ? ? ?

hope its help.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters your HTML you're passing to your `append` function makes no sense:

```
<span style="color:red;">please type your name</p>
```

You open a `<span>` element and then close a `<p>` element.

Answer (score 1):

On a slightly separate note, it looks like you're building some kind of validation...may I suggest using something that's already tried and tested like the [jQuery Validation Plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

It's incredibly mature, and can handle validation situations out of the box...every other scenario can be achieved using custom validator plug-ins.

Some [Demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) can be found here.